# Error when setting "permanent" tooltip option with bindtooltip in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, tooltip

I've got a geoJSON that I load into a map and add tooltips to. Pretty simple, figured that out fine, and now I want the tooltips to be permanent (displayed on map load instead of on marker hover), and I'm getting an error when I try to set that option in bindTooltip.

```
var newLayer= new L.geoJSON().addTo(map).bindTooltip(function(layer) {
   return layer.feature.properties["Property"];
}, {permanent: true, opacity: 0.5});

...later...

$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: "somewebaddress",
   success: function(data) {
   $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
   newLayer.addData(data);
   });
   }
}).error(function() {});
```

If I remove the `permanent: true` option, I have no issues, but of course I do not get the desired permanent tooltip. But when I have that option in there, I get the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

My theory was first that `permanent: true` makes it want to assign the tooltips instantaneously and that since the geoJSON didn't have any data assigned to it yet that was causing the error. But I tried binding the tooltip AFTER adding the data and again, if I have `permanent: true` in there it errors but without it I have no issues, so I guess that's not it.

I'm new to Leaflet, but I feel like this should be simple and I'm at a loss for a solution and struggling to find documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theory is OK, but the diagnosis you are getting comes from the fact that there is no source for GeoJSON layer specified. Empty source should be specified as `[]`. If you had that, the next problem would be what you predicted in your theory.

But there is another problem in your approach. You are using `.bindTooltip` on group layer, not on single feature/layer, as it is intended to be used.

To bind tooltips to features, option `.onEachFeature` is usually used. In your case that should look something like:

```
var newLayer = new L.geoJSON([], {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindTooltip(layer.feature.properties["Property"], {permanent: true, opacity: 0.5});
  }
).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Interesting. `bindTooltip` worked fine with the code I originally provided above, with the exception of when I added the permanent option, in spite of apparently being written wrong as you describe. 

But when I used `.onEachFeature` as you recommended, I get the permanent tooltip I was hoping for. Problem solved, thanks!